# How can I use the values from sqldatareader

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server, ado.net

I want to use the values output by an sql data reader. After modifying I want to update them. I have done the selection part but, I don't know how to use them properly.

```
 #region Get the value from db
        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
            c.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(com,c))
            {
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nickname", nick);
                SqlDataReader s = null;
                s = cm.ExecuteReader();
                while (s.Read())
                {
                    string oras = Convert.ToString(s["Oras"]);
                    string judet = Convert.ToString(s["judet"]);
                    string adresa = Convert.ToString(s["adresa"]);
                }
            }
            c.Close();

        }
        #endregion
        textBox1.Text = oras;
        textBox2.Text = judet;
        textBox3.Text = adresa;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is common way to do it:

```
 using (SqlDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                My_Event _event = new My_Event();
                if (reader["Id"] != DBNull.Value) { _event.ID = (int)reader["Id"]; }
                if (reader["site"] != DBNull.Value) { _event.Site = reader["site"].ToString(); }
                if (reader["time"] != DBNull.Value) { _event.Time = (DateTime)reader["time"]; }
                   _events.AddFirst(_event);
            }
            reader.Close();
        }
```

you check if the value is not `DBNull.Value` and if its not, you cast it to the original type.

Comment: i have done this, but it doesnt get me the value. nick is a global variable made with . in form1 i have global.GlobalVariable= textbox1.text , and here i have nick=Global.GlobalVariable. may this be the problem?

Comment: put a breakpoint in this function and check if your nick has a value. Moreover, i see that you send parameters somewhere but where? Are you trying to execute a stored procedure, or ur sending sql query?

Comment: i send the parametrs here    string com = @"Select (Oras,Judet,Adresa) from informatii where nickname=@nickname";

Answer (score 0):

You need to add and SqlCommand, and Sql Update string and SqlParameters for this:

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
           connectionString))
    {
       SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
       command.Connection.Open();
       command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

Comment: yes , i know but it just doesnt show me the values first. nick is a variable from another form using a global function . form1: global.globalvalue= textbox1.text, and here i  have nick=global.globalvalue may this be the problem?

Comment: @raulbag1996 You should use classes instead of global variables. And isolate the business and data access logic from the view code. Read more about nlayered architecture here, for example: http://layersample.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

you've to change your code as follow

```
#region Get the value from db
        using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(connect))
        {
            c.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cm = new SqlCommand(com,c))
            {
                cm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@nickname", nick);
                SqlDataReader s = null;
                s = cm.ExecuteReader();
                while (s.Read())
                {
                    string oras = Convert.ToString(s["Oras"]);
                    string judet = Convert.ToString(s["judet"]);
                    string adresa = Convert.ToString(s["adresa"]);
                    textBox1.Text = oras;
                    textBox2.Text = judet;
                    textBox3.Text = adresa;
                }
            }
            c.Close();

        }
        #endregion
```